# undefined method `ransack' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation...>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, rubygems

Now I am making job reviewing site. And I would like to create search function on my landing page. So I installed gemfile "ransack". However, when I put "ransack" on my controller, the error "undefined method `ransack' for #" occurred in local environment.

Although I restarted local server and command "gem list ransack" shows that ransack was successfully installed, I couldn't ransack.... What is the cause of problem might be? Thanks for reading.

My controller is like this

Product_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < RankingController
  layout "review_site", :except => :show
  # before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :show
  def index
    @products = Product.order('id ASC').per_page_kaminari(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def search
    @products = Product.where('title LIKE(?)', "%#{params[:keyword]}%").per_page_kaminari(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def landing
    @q = Product.order('id ASC').per_page_kaminari(params[:page]).per(10).ransack(search_params)
    @products = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end
end

private
def search_params
  params.permit(:title_count)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `ransack` on activerecord collection, it should be called on Model class.

```
def landing
  @q = Product.ransack(search_params[:title_count])
  @products = @q.result(distinct: true).order('id ASC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

Refer [`Usage`](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#usage)

Comment: Thank you for your advise. However, I still couldn't understand fully what you said( Sorry,I am very beginner of ruby )... I recognize ransack as "search". 

As Usage(https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#usage) said
 
"Ransack will try to make the class method #search available in your models, but if #search has already been defined elsewhere, you can always use the default #ransack class method. So the following are equivalent:

Article.ransack(params[:q])
Article.search(params[:q])
"
and they clearly use "ransack" in controller. could you elaborate that?  Thanks.

Comment: as it is stated correctly, `Ransack will try to make the class method #search available in your models`, it operates on class and `Product` is model class in your case. Earlier, you tried to call this method on `ActiveRecord Collection` which is not a class but an instance object of `ActiveRecord` class